# SSL CA certificate installation

Tags: java, ssl, https

I have this problem: I am trying to install my SSL certificates correctly so my page is used thru https, I have the following situation:

I went ahead and did the usual: created keystore and private key, created and sent out the .csr file to our CA for approval and got all the SSL certs back. : root.p7b, chain.p7b, website's.p7b and chain.pem

However when I do the importing of the mentioned Certificates I stumbled upon the following error:
"keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Public keys in reply and keystore don't match" Then by reading I found out that Java has it's own cacerts file besides my application's keystore, so I went ahead and installed my root certificate into java's keystore and then I was able to install the rest of the ssl certificates in my applications keystore, but now when I try to acccess my application's web page, my browser (Firefox, Iexplorer) complaint that my applications web page certificate is not legit with the "this connection is untrusted" message, I already tried installing all the certificate I have available sent from my CA into JAVA's cacert file and also installed all of them as well in my application's keystore, have also tried different encoding formats, different order of installation, etc. to no avail!!

Please help. Any advice for little that it might seem is greatly welcome.
Peace
Jesse

Comment: https://github.com/zero11it/acme-client ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe Raghu is correct. Specifically I believe you need to import the chain into your browser truststore (on your local workstation/machine). You've done everything you need to do on the server side from the sounds of it.

The link is pretty old, but it gives the gist of what you need to do:
https://wiki.wmtransfer.com/projects/webmoney/wiki/Installing_root_certificate_in_Internet_Explorer_7

Comment: Thanks for the link, although I forgot to mention that my web server is the venerable Tomcat. Does that change things?

Comment: No, it does not. Because the key here is that tomcat is serving a webpage via SSL that your browser doesn't trust. Importing the chain into your browser's truststore is how you would tell your browser that the certificate used by tomcat is trustworthy (and thereby prevent the message that the browser is giving you telling you that it is not).

Comment: It doesn't look like I can comment to other peoples post - so I'll add a comment here... if you proceed past the prompt given in your browser then you can view the certificate. Make sure that the cert you see here (through your browser) is the one you expect.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the same CA certs to your browser's trust store.

Comment: You see the problem arises because when i try to access the page, the tecnical error says that the certificate in use is selfsigned therefor the page might be a risk! and honestly I don't know why, I have the same certificates in my JAVA cacert file as well as my applications keystore. :-(

Comment: Yes you are expected to get this error for Self-Signed certificates unless you trust them by adding it to Browser trust store. There is nothing un usual here.

Comment: Raghu:  but the cert is not self-signed, i sent my .csr to a well known CA, and the certs that I got back those are the ones giving me trouble.

Comment: Is the domain(CN) of the certificate matches with your environment. For example u must have entered Jess.com as CN where as u will be testing with localhost.

Comment: Help me on this one, but as far as I know, since its an ssl given by a well known CA then the domain would not matter, as the page is freely available to any client thru the internet,. Don't you think?

Comment: Well known CA does not solve all the problems. If the domain doesnt match there will be cross mark on https in the address bar.  According to the browser the certificate is valid only if its domain matches.

Comment: You're absolutely right Raghu, I'll take note of it. The problem was solved because when I proceeded past the prompt I realized that the ssl cert presented by the browser was the one I installed. Honestly I was reluctant to do it, Sorry for my ignorance, but thank you for all your help guys. You helped me put together some of the pieces that where missing in the puzzle.  "Ignorance doesn't kill you, but it makes you sweat a lot" .proverb.

Answer (score 0):

Jesse:

As per the description it seems you are using the Tomcat as a server.

Please try to follow the below steps :

1. First, check the content of the keystore file by running the following command:

> keytool -v -list -keystore sample.jks

2. If you see one only one entry i.e, private key entry scroll down and check the `Issued To` and `Issued By`. If both are the same then the certificate has not been imported in the keystore. Note: copy the alias name (for example test).
3. If that's the case run the below command (assuming you have the p7b file received from the CA)

> keytool -import -keystore sample.jks -alias test - file ca.p7b .

Now run the first command once again and check the content. You should see the certificate imported successfully under the alias.